# Ruby on rails, background image not working the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the follow code:

```
<div class="photoProfile" style="background-image: url(<%= @user.image.url %>)"></div>
```

the variable `@user.image.url` always has value, but the first time, is not attached to the background-image, I need refresh the page and now the image is loaded perfectly.

Some one has and idea of this issue?

Comment: Anything in the logs on the first load of the page?

Comment: @CDub the logs looks normally, if I change the background-image for `<img src="..." />` works. I'm not sure why in the div doesn't works

Comment: Is the source code of the page created any different the first time from the second time?

Comment: @UriAgassi in the same

Comment: Is there anything in the browser console? Like parsing or network errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, and change "asset_path" to "asset_url".

Before)
    `<div style="background-image: url(<%= **asset_path**(get_img(object)) %>)">`

After)
    `<div style="background-image: url(<%= **asset_url**(get_img(object)) %>)">`

but, I cant't understand why it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<%= content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Hello world!"), class: "photoProfile", style: "background-image: url('#{@user.image.url'})") %>
```

**warning just a guess:**
I'm not sure but I guess that html and css is loaded before anything else.
Basically the db hasn't fetched the data yet and html doesn't know what to do with this "string".
If we can manage to load everything in time as erb, it should be possible to show the image?